# Unable to access Ingress service using hostname

Tags: azure, kubernetes, hostname

I created an Ingress Service as below and I am able to get response using the IP (retrieved using the **kubectl get ingress** command).

Deployment File

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1-nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: app1-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app1-nginx
          image: msanajyv/k8s_api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Service File

```css
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1-nginx-clusterip-service
  labels:
    app: app1-nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: app1-nginx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Ingress File

```css
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginxapp1-ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx  
spec:  
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: app1-nginx-clusterip-service
            servicePort: 80
```

With above YAML file I am able to access the service using the ip address i.e., http://xx.xx.xx.xx/weatherforecast .

But I thought of accessing the service using a Domain name instead of IP. So I created a DNS in my azure portal and added a Record set as below.

[image]

[image]

Also I changed my Ingress file as below.

```css
...
  rules:
    - host: app1.msvcloud.io
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: app1-nginx-clusterip-service
            servicePort: 80
```

When I access using the host name (http://app1.msvcloud.io/weatherforecast), the host is not getting resolved. kindly let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

By create a record in your **private** DNS zone, you can only resolve the name (app1.msvcloud.io) within your virtual network. This means it will work if you remote into a VM within the VNET and access from there. But it will not work if you try the same outside the VNET. If you want the name to be resolvable on the world wide web, you need to buy the domain name and register in Azure DNS.

> The records contained in a private DNS zone aren't resolvable from the
> Internet. DNS resolution against a private DNS zone works only from
> virtual networks that are linked to it.

[~What is a private Azure DNS zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-privatednszone).